# Vue: convention for conditional props in dynamic components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am fairly new to Vue, so if what I am doing is absurd, please let me know.

A common convention in many of my components is something like this (only showing relevant parts of code):

```
thing = {text:"some text", href: "https://a.link"}

<template>
  <div>
    <a v-if="thing.href" :href="thing.href">{{thing.text}}</a>
    <span v-else>{{thing.text}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

I dislike this as `thing.text` may in actuality be a lot of stuff (not just text).

Further, I dislike the redundancy for rendering the anchor tag i.e. if there is an `href` be an anchor tag with an `href`.

Thus I would like to shorten and clean this up like so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div :is="complexThing.href ? 'a' : 'span'" :href="complexThing.href">{{complexThing.lotsOfStuff}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Which is nice, we are down to one line, but at the cost of `href` being bound to nothing when it doesn't exist...

So is there a way to *conditionally bind* a prop?

Of course I could wrap this convention into a component of its own. However, I find that what it is, is very dependent on the component I am using it in. I do not like having to copy and paste a chunk of identical code between an if-else statement just to get an href.

Thoughts? Ideas?

e.g.

```
<template>
  <div :is="href ? 'a' : or" :href="href">
  <!-- href=(unknown) will show in inspector if href is undefined -->
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'AnchorOr',
  props: ['or', 'href']
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

which can then be used like:

```
<AnchorOr class="inline-text" :or="span">{{text}}</AnchorOr>
<AnchorOr class="linked-module" :or="div">{{component}}</AnchorOr>
```

Comment: I think that you are thinking way too hard. The first v-if case makes the most sense to me as it is easy to read for anyone. You can handle the v-else where you are displaying "text" which can be a lot of stuff. If you put it in v-else, it doesn't matter what it is. You can easily handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your small example, I would leave it as-is; however if `{{ thing.text }}` were instead a larger template partial then duplicating it is a no-no.

You would normally use [`<component>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) for situations like this:

```vue
<component v-bind="thingProps">{{ thing.text }}</component>
```

```es6
computed: {
  thingProps() {
    return this.thing.href
      ? { is: 'a', href: this.thing.href }
      : { is: 'span' };
  }
}
```